# Switch quantity on integer | *** wasnt declared in this scope

Tags: c++, условия, switch

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

/* run this program using the
console pauser or add your own getch,
system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string lang;
    cout << "Choose your language: rus/eng" << endl;
    cin >> lang;
    switch (lang) { //здесь первая ошибка switch quantity on integer
        case eng:
            cout << "You choose english" << endl; //тут
            break;
        case rus:
            cout << "You choose russian" << endl; //и тут вторая ошибка rus(в случае выше eng) wasnt declared in this scope
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Не первый раз ошибка *** wasnt declared in this scope, так и не могу понять в чем дело

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`switch` нельзя использовать с `string`. Используйте `if ... else`

Comment: Неужели все так просто? А почему нельзя?

Comment: В C++ сравнение строк не является примитивной операцией и дорого стоит

Comment: Что значит примитивная операция???

Comment: @ARHovsepyan операции над примитивными типами

Comment: @hUuueeeyy,  эта конструкция работает только с интегральными типами.  Почему? Это вопрос второй, который вы можете оформить, и вам ответят

Comment: Если прямо очень хочется, то в этой статье описано как достичь этого https://habr.com/post/166201/

Comment: Написал вам в чат по поводу правок, гляньте плиз: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Answer (score 0):

switch нельзя использовать с string.